# Ошибка при добавлении данных в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Установлен Денвер, в нем создана БД, а в ней таблица. Первый раз данные записываются в таблицу нормально, при повторе выдает ошибку записи в таблицу. Если через ПХПадмин удалить эту запись, то можно снова добавить. т.е. больше одной записи в таблицу добавить не получается.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO base(n_01, n_data, n_fio, n_srok_n, n_srok_k, n_1) 
VALUES("'.$n_01.'", "'.$n_data.'", "'.$n_fio.'", "'.$n_srok_n.'","'.$n_srok_k.'","'.$n_1.'")';
if(!mysql_query($sql))
{echo '<center><p><b>Ошибка при добавлении данных!</b></p></center>';} 
else 
{echo '<center><p><b>Данные добавлены!</b></p></center>';}
```

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста какие-нибудь коды. Запроса, скрипта.

Comment: После этого вы еще раз запускаете скрипт и он ничего не добавояет?

Comment: Какое из этих полей Идентификатор? Уставновлен ли Автоинкремент? Установлен ли Первичный ключ?

Comment: Вчера этим скриптом добавил 10 одинаковых записей и они были видны через ПХПадмин, а сегодня стало выдавать ошибку.
Эти данные вносятся через HTML формы

Comment: Чтобы проверить в скрипте ли проблема, введите эти же данные в ПХПМайАдмине и в скрипте. Только напрямую в запросе пропишите значения.

Как было написано в ответе, возможно вы пытаетесь добавить неуникальные данные в уникальное поле.

Answer (score 2):

Если увидеть структуру таблицы было бы понятнее, но, полагаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь вбить в уникальное поле (с инкрементом, например) повторные данные, например, поле id, в которое при первом заходе вы внесли значение 1, затем вы снова пытаетесь внести его, на что мускул, само собой, ругается. Самый просто способ проверить - вывести запрос в браузер и вбить через phpmyadmin - он сразу покажет ошибку.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO base(n_01, n_data, n_fio, n_srok_n, n_srok_k, n_1 ) VALUES("'.$n_01.'", "'.$n_data.'", "'.$n_fio.'", "'.$n_srok_n.'","'.$n_srok_k.'","'.$n_1.'" )';
if(!mysql_query($sql)) {echo 'Ошибка при добавлении данных!'.$sql;} else {echo 'Данные добавлены!';}
```

либо так

```
<?
$sql = 'INSERT INTO base(n_01, n_data, n_fio, n_srok_n, n_srok_k, n_1 ) VALUES("'.$n_01.'", "'.$n_data.'", "'.$n_fio.'", "'.$n_srok_n.'","'.$n_srok_k.'","'.$n_1.'" )'; 
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
?>
```

Comment: Выдает следующее 

>`Notice: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'n_01'INSERT INTO base(n_01, n_data, n_fio, n_srok_n, n_srok_k, n_1 ) VALUES("", "", "", "","","" ) in Z:\home\prokat.by\www\priem.php on line 90`

Comment: Вот вам и ответ

>Если увидеть структуру таблицы было бы понятнее, но полагаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь вбить в уникальное поле (с инкрементом, например) повторные данные, например, поле id, в которое при первом заходе вы внесли значение 1, затем вы снова пытаетесь внести его

Comment: в вашем случае, нужно поле id сделать автоинкрементным. и при каждом инсерте с n_01 = 0, строке будет присвоен уникальный идентификатор.

Comment: или вообще в запрос инсерт не ставить "n_01"